# Order and filter Server-Sent-Events in angular.js eventsource

Tags: java, angularjs, jax-rs, server-sent-events

I have a client in AngularJS where I consume multiple SSE (Server-Sent-Events) in Java from the Server Side (there are multiple endpoints in different web servers in the backend).

[image: Diagram link]

Note: I have to use SSE.

I currently register a listener to each type of event coming from each SSE connection, such as:

```
source.addEventListener('alpha', function(e) {
  doSomething();
}, false);
```

The purpose is to show a notification based on these events, and with this I have a few questions:

- How can the client know if the information has changed in the backend?
- How to organise and filter these events? For example, by receiving simultaneously multiple events from multiple connections, how can I manage them in order to show the client an specific notification regarding an specific event?

  Note: I'm not only talking only about organising an event per type, but I also need to have in mind if an event is more important than another.

  So far I only think of receiving all the events, and save them in a list that I could order and filter. Is there a problem if two SSE events are fired at the same time? Do you know of an example of this?
- Is it a good idea to make the logic for organising the events on the client side?
- Should I create a database for these events?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

In the client side you need to make ajax calls periodically to know if there is change data in the server (SSE). In angularjs there is `$http and $q` service for server side call. you can use `$scope.$watch` as well.

In JavaScript there is not way to handle the way android handles push notification.

You can also see the web socket option if its matches your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Aniruddha Das. I have a few questions:
- Why do I have to make periodically calls to the server to know if there's change in the data? Can't the SSE events send new data if and only if something has changed in the server? And if not, isn't it possible to just compare old data with the new data received from the same event in AngularJS ? [I'm asking because maybe these are not the best approaches]

P.D. Unfortunately I have to use SSE.

Comment: As you want to notify your user if there anything changed from server side. If the user browser is open, he don't need to refresh, you just have to periodically make call to update user browser

Comment: I see. Ok, one last question. Do you think it's a good idea to make the logic for organising the events on the client side? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, UI is grown a lot and you can manage almost everything there. I would say choose a good framework manage your codes